# Does #4 LDPE Plastic Bottle Leach into Water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, polymers, plastics

I understand that Water Bottles expire due only to the fact that the plastic can degrade over time and leach into the water making the water's taste not as desirable as the manufacturer might intend.

Does anyone happen to know the degradation rate/expiration for #4 LDPE? I'm using a plastic water storage vessel for long term water storage in m emergency preparedness supplies and would like to make sure the plastic doesn't leach. Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: For long term storage, the plastic vessel is not the only factor, but also water itself, catching smells and growing life. Note that plastic leaching is not directly related to plastic degradation.Degradation is rather related to releasing plastic microparticles, while leaching is diffusion of minor components from plastics to water ( like phthalates used as plasticisers ).

Comment: The key is regular water replacement and occasional container cleaning. Durability of PE is not a concern, aside of manipulation weariness and optical unusability to serve any more.